# custom UI for drop down

Tags: android, xml, spinner

i am in process of making a custom UI for my app, have almost created XML based shapes for all the controls which is fine, but spinner seems to be the main problem, is their any example for making a new shape for spinner, which could be supported on 1.5 to 2.2, i know about a tutorial that tells for custom shape for spinner but that`s for less then 1.5, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Have you managed to do it?
I'd suggest you make an XML Drawable like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item  android:state_pressed="true"
   android:state_focused="false">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#535151" />
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#000000" />
            <corners android:radius="3dp" />
            <padding android:left="1dp"
                android:top="1dp"
                android:right="1dp"
                android:bottom="1dp" />
        </shape>
 </item>  
</selector>
```

And then use it as the background for your spinner in the 'main.xml':

```
<Spinner
 android:background="@drawable/spinner_design"
 android:id="@+id/customSpinner"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

In order to make your spinner design look coherent, you should also make your own `<TextView>` design for the spinner and use similar background colours for both the `<TextView>` as well as the `XML Drawable Shape`.

Comment: i have managed to do it by using layer list, let me know if you need to see a snap shot